# Showing tabbed content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a module where, when the user hovers overs a `.header`, the image on the right hand side will change. Something similar to the "Explore the collections" module found on [this page](https://tylko.com/?ref=land-book.com).

With my current approach, I'm encountering the following issues:

1. On hover of a non-active `.header` (i.e. "header 2" from the demo below), I want that red circle to replace the yellow one.
2. "Header 1" is also still active (`.active` styles are shown) when hovering over "header 2".

**Current approach:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.tabs__li .header').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('active');
 })

 // add class .active on li hover
 $('.tabs__li').mouseenter(function () {
  $('.tab__item').addClass('active');
 });

})
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span.header{
  color: #ABABAB;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab__item.active .header{
  color: #454544;
}

span.header:hover{
   color: #454544;
}

.tabbed__left,
.tabbed__right {
   flex-basis: 50%;
}

.tabbed__right{
    display: none;
    min-height: 325px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.active .tabbed__right{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<div class="tabbed">

  <ul class="tabs d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
  
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row active">
      <div class="tabbed__left"><li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-1"><span class="header">Header 1</span></li></div>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-1" style="background-image:url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/5a50me.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row">
      <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-2"><span class="header">Header 2</span></li>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-2" style="background-image:url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/2zdr4f7.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e19ku74m/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not referencing your current hovered item in your approach but isntead just applying the `active` class to every element.

You can remove the active class for all elements and then just apply it the to elemnt in reference to `this` (the element triggering the event handler):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tabs__li .header').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
  })

  // add class .active on li hover
  $('.tabs__li').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.tab__item').addClass('active');
    // or alternatively 
    // $(this).closest('.tab__item').addClass('active');

  });

})
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span.header {
  color: #ABABAB;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab__item.active .header {
  color: #454544;
}

span.header:hover {
  color: #454544;
}

.tabbed__left,
.tabbed__right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.tabbed__right {
  display: none;
  min-height: 325px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.active .tabbed__right {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<div class="tabbed">

  <ul class="tabs d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">

    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row active">
      <div class="tabbed__left">
        <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-1"><span class="header">Header 1</span></li>
      </div>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-1" style="background-image:url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/5a50me.jpg);"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row">
      <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-2"><span class="header">Header 2</span></li>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-2" style="background-image:url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/2zdr4f7.jpg);"></div>
    </div>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7rqpjbf/

Comment: Legend, got it working, thanks for explaining it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `parents` jquery selector to find the click tab and apply the `active` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.tabs__li .header').click(function(){
   $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parents('.tab__item').addClass('active');
 })

 // add class .active on li hover
 $('.tabs__li').mouseenter(function () {
   $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('.tab__item').addClass('active');
 });

})
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span.header{
  color: #ABABAB;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab__item.active .header{
  color: #454544;
}

span.header:hover{
   color: #454544;
}

.tabbed__left,
.tabbed__right {
   flex-basis: 50%;
}

.tabbed__right{
    display: none;
    min-height: 325px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.active .tabbed__right{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<div class="tabbed">

  <ul class="tabs d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
  
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row active">
      <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-1"><span class="header">Header 1</span></li>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-1" style="background-image:url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/5a50me.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-row">
      <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-2"><span class="header">Header 2</span></li>
      <div class="tabbed__right" id="tab-2" style="background-image:url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/2zdr4f7.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/ry8g72Lz/5/